# Является ли грамотность формой снобизма?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я знаю, что надо говорить "звонИт" и именно так и говорю. Еще я говорю "обеспЕчение", хотя это и вызывает у меня некоторые затруднения (всегда надо немного подумать, прежде чем сказать). Но ведь подавляющее большинство говорят "звОнит" и "обеспечЕние", причем не задумываясь и без всяких сомнений.

Значит, такое произношение естественно для человека. И все же правильным считается то, что посчитала таковым небольшая группа (я бы даже сказала группка) экспертов.

Конечно, иногда неграмотное написание нарушает/затемняет смысл высказывания: например, "поедим" в фразе "поедим на юг". Но часто никакой смысловой разницы между вариантами нет, они просто отражают традицию. *Дополнение для [[@Gecube](/users/972/gecube)](/users/972/gecube)*. Я имею в виду письменный вариант. Это из e-mail-ов моего второго мужа ;-))

Не подумайте, что я против грамотности: я сама стараюсь выражаться литературно и правильно. Но могу ли я этого требовать от других?

У меня возникают два вопроса.

1. Почему человечество так держится за свои исключения? Какой глубокий философский, социальный, психологический и т.п. смысл есть в том, чтобы массово заучивать правила, которые не кажутся большинству людей естественными?
2. Является ли этот смысл достаточно важным, чтобы превращать его в орудие "репрессий" на государственном уровне: ГИА, ЕГЭ и т.п.?

Не подумайте, что я ерничаю или издеваюсь. Я действительно подозреваю, что какой-то смысл во всем этом есть. Но вот осознать и сформулировать его не могу...

**Дополнение**. Я хотела поставить вопрос философски, не знаю, получилось ли. Наверное, его надо адресовать в первую очередь специалистам по анализу систем. Но они должны учитывать и чисто лингвистическую сторону.

**Дополнение для [[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus)**. А что, кто-то здесь уже ругал академиков? Не заметила. Может, у Вашего страха просто глаза велики? Вообще-то я хотела поговорить о самоорганизации общества и о том, насколько в этом процессе важны действия отдельных его членов, выделенных/выделившихся в каком-то аспекте.

Кстати, к снобам, о которых говорится в заголовке, я отношу вовсе не академиков, а себя. Потому что я морщусь от "позвОнит" и "квАртал".

Кстати, Вы как раз *можете* помешать неправильному направлению форума, так как имеете права наравне с модераторами. Только подождите пару дней, дайте людям высказаться. Если разговор пойдет не туда - удаляйте. Берите ответственность на себя!
**А как было в истории?** Современное отношение к грамотности, как мне кажется, родилось недавно. Много веков язык развивался свободно, не регулируемый никакими государственными установлениями. И тем не менее, выполнял свои функции, от коммуникации до создания национальной идентичности. Еще менее 100 лет назад, когда начался ликбез, целью было просто научить читать и писать.
Почему же потом государство настолько озаботилось проблемой, что сделало ее краеугольным камнем системы образования? (наряду с математикой).

- Может, причина в развитии СМИ и вовлечении людей в открытую коммуникацию?
- Или привитие норм правильной речи - один из способов привития человеку самой идеи общественной нормы?
- Или это способ уравнять людей, слепить из них единый класс (потому что, конечно, речь часто выдает в человеке его происхождение и круг общения).
- Может, были и другие причины.

Интересно также было бы сравнить отечественный опыт с зарубежным, особенно в "демократических" государствах, которые провозглашают индивидуализм социальной ценностью.

Comment: На самом деле у культуры есть важная функция разделения людей на "своих" и "чужих". В первую очередь это было важно для дикарей. Но мы то вроде цивилизованные люди, живущие в эпоху глобализма, тогда почему же эта функция все еще не пропадает? Наверное, потому что это разделение кому-то выгодно?

Comment: Пока Ваш ответ наиболее адекватный (по существу). Но хотелось бы его углУбить. Почему обществу важна национальная/историческая идентичность? Кто ее осознает и кто принимает решение? У кого есть права на насаждение/изменение речевых норм? и т.п. 

Наверное, эти вопросы уже выходят за рамки форума, они относятся к философии, социологии, психологи и т.п.  А на уровне этого форума вопрос действительно можно считать риторическим...

Comment: Думаю, в жизнеспособной системе каждая тенденция должна быть уравновешена противоположной. Поэтому, чем больше глобализма, тем больше стремление к отличию, к образованию маленькой группы.

Comment: Думаю, это "выгодно" человеку и человечеству.  Человек давно понял, что, не следуя нормам, он погибнет во всех смыслах этого слова.

Comment: > Человек давно понял, что, не следуя нормам, он погибнет во всех смыслах этого слова.  

Согласна. Только хотелось бы уточнить, что здесь понимается по "человеком". Не всякий же человек с улицы. Большинство людей не задумывается, как они говорят, а просто повторяют то, к чему привыкли. Да и вообще не задумываются о таких глобальных вопросах.  
Значит, это дело "элиты" (в некотором смысле)? Или сама общественная система неявно подталкивает человека к такому поведению?

Comment: > А что, кто-то здесь уже ругал академиков?   

Вот именно, что здесь пока еще нет. Но, боюсь, теперь уже недолго здать. 

DocentI, 99% смертных считают, что вероятность выпадения орла возрастает после десяти решек. Что ж теперь, теорию вероятностей пересматривать? Или приходить на матфорумы плакаться о своей трудной судьбе?

Все, действительно уже надолело говорить ни о чем.

Comment: > 99% смертных считают, что вероятность выпадения орла возрастает после десяти решек

А это какое отношение имеет к данному вопросу?

Comment: А какое отношение ваш вопрос имеет ко мне?

Comment: С того самого момента, как Вы начали отвечать =)

Comment: 2 янв 2012 – 1.11 Декабря 8. 1.12 Год 2000 апреля 43 числа. 1.13 Мартобря 86 числа. Между днем и ночью. 1.14 Никакого числа. День был без числа.

Поздравлю, DocentI, срач начался.
Все, ребята, дальше без меня. Сколько раз зарекался не возвращаться...

Comment: @behemothus, да не переживайте Вы так! Прямо жалко стало Вас...  
Возьмите и удалите то, что Вам не нравится. Будьте модератором своей судьбы!  

Я, честное слово, не обижусь!  

Кстати, я попала в положение, подобное Вашему, "у себя", на математике. Поцапалась с ферматистами. Но я же не делаю из этого трагедии! Ферматисты и другие чудики были и будут, это уж закон природы...

Comment: Исәнмесез, @виктор1799. Я ужасно люблю заниматься языком. И сына к этому приучаю. Мин татар телен биш тапкыр өйрәнәрге башландым. (Татарский, кстати, очень интересный язык, особенно тем, что не входит в индоевропейскую группу).  
Но вот когда у нас признали татарский государственным и обещали не принимать на работу тех, кто его не знает... Это вызвало некоторую, мягко говоря, напряженность.  
Просто "дьявол прячется в деталях". Я прекрасно понимаю, что и языком, и математикой заниматься надо. Но "специалист подобен флюсу" - многое сводится к "ловле блох", разным несущественным тонкостям.

Comment: Интересно, какие вопросы кажутся @behemothus хорошими? Про одно и два "н"? Про вместе-раздельно с не? Про ударения? Про то, каким падежом управляет глагол? Все это, конечно, мило и интересно, но очень уж мелко. Размаху нет!

Comment: > мне почему-то кажется, что вопрос о том, почему общество особое внимание уделяет языковым нормам, а не ритмике, к примеру, Вы поставили в спешке.  

Не в спешке, а как полемическое заострение. Я верю, что языки "важнее", но не могу объяснить себе, почему.

Comment: Но языки не важнее, чем математика и логика...

Comment: Кому как. Кто к чему способен. Я большой пессимист и считаю, что некоторым людям просто не дается тот уровень формализации, который нужен в логике и математике. Впрочем, глубокое (научное) изучение лингвистики также требует очень четкого мышления.  

Недаром же лингвистикой интересуются многие математики (например, великий Колмогоров, создавший свою концепцию падежа).  

Еще я слышала предложение, чтобы русский язык в школе преподавали не "литераторы", а математики. В этом что-то есть!

Comment: Ну, правила языка должны быть логичными, чтобы их запоминать. Или все должно быть подано в увлекательной форме с наглядными примерами, но в нашей системе образования этого не достает. Мне очень понравилась книга [Секреты орфографии][1]. Очень обидно, но второй ее части я так и не нашел.

[1]:http://textgenetic.ucoz.ru/load/knigi_po_masterstvu_slova/uchebniki_russkogo_jazyka/sekrety_orfografii/4-1-0-6

Comment: Отвечу @gecube
На самом деле у культуры есть важная функция разделения людей на "своих" и "чужих". В первую очередь это было важно для дикарей. Но мы то вроде цивилизованные люди, живущие в эпоху глобализма, тогда почему же эта функция все еще не пропадает? Наверное, потому что это разделение кому-то выгодно?   
Скорее всего, это естественно. Не должны и не могут все люди быть в одном статусе, как считали в бывшем Союзе. Эта идея канула в Лету. Каждый для себя решает, хочет ли он быть грамотным или нет, желает ли уважать и любить родной язык, каким он есть в учебниках. Проблема в мотивации...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да-а, можно трактаты писать по этому вопросу)) И раз его задали, значит, проблема есть. Может, он связан с другим вопросом: почему так мало людей, даже студентов филфаков (из собственного опыта: реально мало моих бывших сокурсников можно назвать грамотными) знают родной язык на приличном уровне, не говоря уже про 100-процентную грамотность (это вообще мифическое понятие)? Вот что приходит в голову. Во-первых, русский язык - ОЧЕНЬ сложный, особенно для иностранцев (вот уж кому я не завидую в этом плане). Во-вторых, почти полностью отсутствует мотивация (родной язык изучать непрестижно, денег много не заработаешь, в общем, дело это неблагодарное). Чтобы что-то изменить в лучшую сторону, выходит, надо: 1) развивать язык упрощая по возможности правила; 2) мотивировать: заинтересовывать, увлекать, поощрять, преподавать доступно (побольше пряника, поменьше кнута). Черт возьми, красив все-таки русский язык, и богат. Многие нероссияне хотят на нем разговаривать (правда, эту тему лучше не развивать).

Несколько слов об английском языке. Думаю, он справедливо считается развитым языком: он лаконичен, относительно простой для изучения (по сравнению с китайским, русским или французским...) и очень популярен. Есть еще и политический фактор (во многих странах он насаждался с приходом британских колонизаторов, к примеру, да и Америка имеет сильное влияние на весь мир). Но - парадокс: американцы не знают грамматику английского (пока еще не "американского") языка. Они интуитивно знают, где надо использовать простое прошедшее, а где Present Perfect или Past Рerfect. А правил не знают. И сами признают, что русские лучше знают грамматику английского, чем они сами. Но это еще не значит, что они, американцы, "тупые". Да, они коверкают слова, сокращая их до невозможности (*What r u waiting 4?* - это еще не самый яркий пример). Вот не знаю, как к этому относится тамошнее министерство образования. Мне кажется, довольно лояльно. И не знаю, плохо это или хорошо. Мне кажется, просто английский так стремительно развивается, что никакие министерства не в состоянии это контролировать. Ну да Бог с ними, англоязычными. Пусть себе не учат правил. В этом плане с них, с американцев в данном случае, пример брать не стоит. Но вот тенденцию по возможности упрощать определенные языковые правила (очень при этом осторожно и деликатно) позаимствовать можно. Думаю, это пойдет всем русскоязычным только на пользу.

Собственно по вопросу. Думаю, в некоторой степени грамотные люди и есть снобы, по сравнению с неграмотными. Так же, как богатые по отношению к бедным. Но это зависит от высокомерия отдельно взятого человека. В идеале надо быть толерантными к тем, кто слабее. Особенно если "сильные мира сего" желают расширить свой круг общения, свою "тусовку". Если нет, то так и останутся снобами и будут жадно упиваться своим "величием", ни с кем не делясь.

Comment: Наконец-то ответ "по делу", на вопрос! Спасибо Вам! А то народ увлекся ЕГЭ и ударениями, хотя это были только иллюстрации.  
> Но это зависит от высокомерия отдельно взятого человека. В идеале надо быть толерантными к тем, кто слабее.  
Не совсем согласна. От высокомерия зависит, буду ли я _демонстрировать_ свое отношение.   
Вот я математик. Я же могу дружить с человеком, который забыл, как решать квадратное уравнение? Это мне совсем не будет мешать. Но, согласитесь, мне трудно быть другом тому, кто пишет "здаровье" и не может составить правильную фразу (т.е. правильную с моей точки зрения).

Comment: А давайте разберемся, кто же такой сноб в современном понимании. Вынесу этот вопрос отдельно на обсуждение. А тогда уже сделаем выводы про сноба-лингвиста.

Comment: Ну конечно, я использовала слово "сноб" не совсем аккуратно. Это просто форма небольшой провокации. Несмотря на почтенный возраст, я остаюсь немного анфан террибль :-))  

А со словом разберитесь, почему бы и не разобраться? Только я не имела в виду обязательно лингвистов (сама-то я тоже сноб, хотя и математик)

Comment: Ок, тогда разберемся и с математиками-снобами :))) и просто с теми, кто умеет грамотно писать))

Comment: Нашла анекдот:  
> В зависимости от того, лОжат плитку или кладут, цены прыгают от 10 до 50 долларов за метр.

Comment: Ну вот, разве не стимул быть грамотным строителем-ремонтником :))

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что здесь кроется несколько моментов. Во-первых, существует корпус чиновников от языка. Которым нужно создавать самим себе работу. Бюрократия всегда порождает бюрократию. Во-вторых, существует масса диалектов и говоров. В каждом из которых есть свои нюансы. И по ударению, и по смыслам. Не говорю уже про профессиональный слэнг и технический язык. При этом чтобы все могли друг с другом договориться, нужно выбрать какой отдельный вариант языка, чтобы все его изучали в школе. В третьих, язык развивается. Как говорили сто лет тому назад и как сейчас говорят - две большие разницы, как говорят в Одессе. Те правила, которые сейчас имеются, могут лишь фиксировать текущие нормы. А норма есть понятие статистическое. Но уж точно никак не диктовать. С другой стороны, должны существовать какие-то ограничение, чтобы мы не скатывались с падонкафскому языку (превед, медвед и пр.). В четвертых, язык нужен для общения. Если иностранец или русскоязычный произнесет "зв***о***нит" или "обеспeч***е***ние", то я его прекрасно пойму. Следовательно, задача выполнена. Но если будут коверкаться окончания, неправильно спрягаться и склоняться слова, то мне, честно говоря, будет как минимум неуютно и попытки понять, что же пытаются мне сказать, будут требовать слишком много усилий.

> Конечно, иногда неграмотное написание нарушает/затемняет смысл высказывания: например, "поедим" в фразе "поедим на юг".

А произносится-то эта фраза как? Ударение на "е", следовательно вторая "е" в слове "поедем" при произношении приближается к "и". Вот вам и "регулярная" структура русского языка. Хотя мне лично в голову никогда не придет произнести "по***е***дем" как "по***е***дим".

Comment: Эти причины, конечно, существуют, но они лежат "на поверхности". Еще бы я добавила консерватизм системы образования. Языки преподавали в гимназиях (заведение для "чистой" публики), а теперь преподают и в массовой школе.  
Но может все же есть более сущностные причины? Например, китайцы "мучаются" со своими иероглифами и не переходят на буквенное письмо. Но это позволяет сохранить специфическую культуру.

Comment: Китайцев и японцев лучше не трогать. Это вообще отдельная культура, которую нужно понимать и чувствовать. Не всем европейцам это дано. Лучше в качестве примеров искать что-то более близкое. Вроде Европы или Америки.

>Но это позволяет сохранить специфическую культуру.

Ну, вообще-то существует огромный пласт культуру. Литературной. Достоевский, Пушкин, Есенин, Горький... Никто ж ведь ее не выкидывает, даже если и будут производить какие-либо реформы. Да и смешно это было бы: переводить того же Пушкина с русского на русский :-)

Comment: Все-таки чего же больше в обучении грамотности: инерции или культурообразующих смыслов? 

Помню, я как-то спросила одного декана, как они собираются отбирать абитуриентов на свою экономическую специальность? Он ответил: да сделаем экзамен по математике посложнее. Конечно, сортировку поступающих они сделают, но что она будет отражать? Не так ли и ЕГЭ по русскому: что-то проверяет, но то ли, что нужно обществу?

Comment: Переводят же Шекспира на английский ;-))  
Даже не имея высокой грамотности я могу _прочитать_ названных Вами авторов. Но обязательно ли мне _говорить_ так же как они? Их стилем, с их (историческими) особенностями речи?

Comment: > Не так ли и ЕГЭ по русскому: что-то проверяет, но то ли, что нужно обществу?

Думаю, что нет. Но я на это повлиять не могу. А могу только смириться и набрать свои... сколько-то там баллов. =) Хорошо, что мне как гр. РФ не нужно никуда подтверждать свои языковые навыки. А редактором в газету или на аналогичную работу, требующую очень хорошего знания языка, не пойду. Но тем не менее, мне очень грустно, что в уважаемых изданиях я умудряюсь находить опечатки, причем весьма серьезные, или некорректно составленные фразы.

Comment: Да и мне грустно... Хотя я не могу рационально объяснить эту грусть. Ну сказал человек: "Подъезжая к станции у меня упала шляпа". Смысл понятен, так чего же переживать? Наверное, такое переживание - просто стереотип, вбитый с детства. И есть в нем некий снобизм "культурного" человека.

Comment: > Смысл понятен, так чего же переживать?
Ну, сложно сказать. Кто подъезжал? Человек или шляпа? Да и звучит, честно говоря, не очень. Другое дело, когда такой оборот в составе предложение с большим кол-вом слов. Тогда слух резать будет меньше, но смысловая проблема все равно будет иметь место.

Answer (score 3):

Всё зависит от конкретной ситуации. Грамотность - это признак высокой культуры. Нужно внутренне чувствовать, где заканчивается "территория" высокой культуры и начинается "территория", на которой демонстрация высокого уровня культуры не только никого не впечатлит, но и скорее всего будет раздражать.

В кругу людей, считающих себя (и друг друга) носителями высокой культуры, следует стараться говорить и писать правильно, и нет ничего снобистского в том, чтобы указывать другим на ошибки. Там же, где люди на высокий уровень не претендуют и общаются так, как им удобно, лучше свою грамотность особо не педалировать. Специально опускаться до низкого уровня окружающих, конечно, не нужно. Но можно спокойно расслабиться и не придавать этому особого значения. Можно даже попытаться копировать чужие ошибки, не забывая о том, что это всё-таки ошибки. Иногда это может оказаться забавным. Главное, чтобы люди не подумали, что таким образом ты над ними издеваешься. И уж точно не следует указывать на ошибки людям, чья культура заметно ниже. Потому что это как раз и будет тот самый снобизм, который раздражает.

Comment: Мы уже обсудили понятие _снобизм_ в [другом вопросе](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/8124/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8). Сноб - не обязательно тот, кто _демонстрирует_ свое превосходство.  
Вот я знаю математику, а кто-то - не знает, но я отношусь к нему, как к равному. Но если человек грубо неграмотен, я в душе буду ставить его на низкую ступеньку. Хотя виду и не покажу.

Comment: Ни один из ответов в том другом вопросе меня не впечатлил. Больше всего на правду похож самый популярный, но и он неверен, поскольку исходит из обязательной необоснованности претензий на превосходство. А если бы претензии были обоснованными, то это якобы уже не был бы снобизм. В действительности обоснованность претензий роли не играет роли. Главное, чтобы превосходство подчёркнуто демонстрировалось. Сноб - это не содержательная категория, которая описывает то, кем является человек, а категория, обозначающая его субъективную самоидентификацию в социальном пространстве.

Comment: Ну ладно, в название этого вопроса я внесла элемент хулиганства, эпатажа. Дело же не в смысле слова "сноб", а в том, что грамотность, в отличие от наличия других знаний, играет также социальную роль, является индикатором "культурного статуса" человека. Все учатся в школе, но люди из разных общественных слоев говорят и пишут по-разному. То есть существует как бы несколько параллельных языков. Но только один из них имеет статус "государственного" - литературный.

Comment: И в чём тут вопрос? Вполне естественное состояние дел. Единственный носитель языка, широко распространённый в пространстве и хорошо сохраняющийся во времени, - это литература, написанная на этом языке (во всей своей совокупности). Тот вариант языка, на котором написана она, объединяет всех и сразу - как разные регионы, так и разные поколения людей. Какой же ещё вариант языка государство могло взять для решения своих задач?

Comment: Вот именно "своих задач". А народ-то и не спросили. У нас в республике тоже татарский язык государственный. И я понимаю, что это нужно для сохранения нации. Но если сейчас начнут этот закон жестко проводить в жизнь... Как бы не получить очередную локальную войну.

Comment: Для сохранения нации это как раз не нужно и даже, наоборот, вредит. Но это нужно для сохранения этнической идентичности. Думаю, именно её вы и имели в виду. Это очень распространённая ошибка. Нация и этнос - это в некотором смысле противоположные вещи. Нацией называется форма государственного устройства, основанная на том, что этническая принадлежность граждан не играет никакой роли. Для укрепления нации нужен русский язык. Точнее, был бы нужен, если бы она была. Сейчас у нас нации нет вообще. Это раньше была советская нация, которую объединял русский язык.

Answer (score 3):

Является ли грамотность формой снобизма? У кого как. Когда я служил в армии, то умным меня считали за то, что сумел без мата пересказать первую часть "Матрицы", про то что "в армии матом не ругаются, а разговаривают" - промолчим. Это нисколько не мешало общаться и даже учится у этих людей, в том числе и языку (до армии я русский-матерный знал лишь на уровне "со словарём").

Если говорить о философии и рассуждениях, зачем выпячивать именно языковые нормы, ответ простой - незачем. Нет, конечно если человеку необходимо выступать на публике, нужно, чтоб обращали внимание на содержание,  а не форму, а для этого речь и устная, и письменная должны соответствовать некой норме. Сам литературный язык формируется именно тогда, когда это публичность в виде писателей и журналистов появляется в массах образованного слоя.

То есть, если ваша публичность ограничена кругом ваших знакомых, то литературность языка ни к чему,  главное, чтобы понимали.

Однако, так как именно публичные люди диктуют моду и общественные нормы, то и на грамотность речи обращают внимания больше, чем на умение решать квадратные уравнения.

Answer (score 2):

> Но ведь подавляющее большинство говорят "звОнит" и "обеспечЕние", причем не задумываясь и без всяких сомнений.

"Подавляющее большинство" людей говорит на китайском.
"Подавляющее большинство" людоедов голосует девятью голосами за съедение десятого.
"Подавляющее Большинство", не будь контролера, ездило бы в общественном транспорте без билета.
И вообще, "демократия это воля большинства и права меньшинства" (кажется, Черчиль), а не наоборот.

Вопрос, простите, ... (да-да, оно самое), при всем к вам уважении. 
Во-первых, далеко не факт, что большинство говорит именно так, как вы полагаете.
Во-вторых, оринетироваться надо не на большинство, а на всех. И тут нет прямой и равной демократии по принципу "один человек - один голос". Тут правит просвещенный абсолютизм. 
Язык должен быть конвервативным и меняться только вместе с глобальными нормами, а не по частным поводам.

Касательно ваших примеров. ЗвонИт-звОнит в некотором смысле на такую норму претендует, но очень слабенько (о том - ниже), обеспечЕнье - ну никак, мне режет слух жутко, напоминает обезварЕнье и обесконфечивание.

Возвращаясь к звОнит. В русском языке последнее время наблюдается тенденция к смещению ударения на основу в третьем лице глаголов учит, курит, поит, доит, багрянит, облегчит, звонит, включит, вкручит и некоторых других. Но они находятся в разной стадии этого процесса. Из этого списка (их, разумеется, много больше) первые два окончательно избавились от сторой нормы, доит, поит и багрянит - имеют два равноправных ударения, остальные пока не претендуют на нормативность, хотя некоторым глаголам из этой группы словари иногда "разрешают" уарение на первом слоге как просторечный или разговорный вариант (не называю, ибо спорно). Огромное же большинство таких глаголов пока сохряняют историческую норму с ударением на глагольном суффиксе.

Comment: @behemothus, Вы меня разочаровали своим ответом. Разве дело в конкретных словах? Это только так, пример... Я хочу понять, почему общество так ценит эту преемственность, что готово тратить на нее деньги, силы, время и нервы учеников (и их родителей). Я смутно чувствую, что что-то за этим кроется, может, очень глубокое. А Вы мне очередную агитку предлагаете!  

- Почему на детей надевают длинные рубашечки?
- Но, сэр, не надевать же на бедных малюток короткие!  > Дж.К.Джером.

Ваш ответ напоминает этот, и по глубине аргументов, и по излишней эмоциональности. Простите...

Comment: Мой первый муж говорит "фенОмен", но "средствА". Потому что он вырос в деревне, а учился в МГУ. Ну привык он так! И почему я имею право его поправлять? Потому что я, типа, интеллигент? 

Кстати, второй муж тоже считает, что в бухгалтерском смысле надо говорить "средствА".  

В общем, рассталась с обоими ;-))

Comment: О, место вакантно? :-) Шучу.

Comment: @Галактион уже сватал меня за @behemotрus, но, судя по баллам, это был бы ужасный мезальянс...

Comment: >@behemothus, Вы меня разочаровали своим ответом. Разве дело в конкретных словах?  

Взаимно. Вы меня сильно разочаровали своим вопросом.  
Дело именно в словах. "Принципов" я тут не вижу.  
Добавить нечего.

Comment: Почему разочаровала? Я же не предлагаю отменить грамотность или обучение ей. Просто хочу разобраться в важном для общества и для меня вопросе.  
Наверное, у меня слишком большая склонность к глобализации вопросов. Вам, видимо, больше нравится конкретика.  

Я уже не первый раз поднимаю эту тему, и замечаю, что меня воспринимают как "борца с грамотностью" (или как "борца за грамотность"). Но я ни то, ни другое. Я хочу ПОНЯТЬ.

Comment: >Почему разочаровала?  

Я не могу воспрепятствовать превращению ещё и этого форума в поле очередного срача на тему снобов-академиков, запрещающих писать корову через ять, но участвовать в этом не собираюсь.

DIXI

Answer (score 2):

Следила за всей дискуссией. Мне понравился ответ и behemothus, и Виктора. Но не отвечала, так как слишком уж много разных вопросов Вы объединили: и этические, и философские, и  даже проблемы обучения языку в современной школе и необходимости такого такой формы контроля, как ЕГЭ. На все не буду отвечать, а вот мимо ЕГЭ пройти не могу.

> Является ли этот смысл достаточно важным, чтобы превращать его в орудие "репрессий" на государственном уровне: ГИА, ЕГЭ и т.п.?
>
> Не так ли и ЕГЭ по русскому: что-то проверяет, но то ли, что нужно обществу?
>
> Веками язык развивался свободно, никто не заставлял людей (будь они даже дворянского происхождения) разбираться в падежах и наклонениях, думаю, даже не было точно известно, сколько "н" надо писать. И вот - на тебе! ЕГЭ!

Чем же не угодил ЕГЭ? Или он предстоит Вашему сыну и Вы опасаетесь, что будет слишком сложно? Какое отношение имеете Вы к ЕГЭ по русскому, сколько вариантов заданий сделали, чтобы называть "ЕГЭ" орудием репрессий.  Предыдущая форма контроля (сочинение)по сути своей была гораздо сложнее, чем ЕГЭ . Просто списывало  большинство в обычных школах. (Сборники "золотых" сочинений ни для кого не секрет). Это не экзамен был. а профанация  экзамена и позор всеобщий (учителя меня поймут). . Слава Богу, что вот такая независимая форма оценки знаний появилась. И двойки. Не могут у нас все дети в стране сдавать успешно в силу социальных причин. А сам по себе экзамен вполне по силам. Там есть о чем спорить, что менять. Но уже сейчас 17 -то баллов из 64 способны набрать все, если хоть немножко захотят и будут присутствовать на занятиях. А перспектива независимой оценки на ЕГЭ служит стимулом к занятиям.

> 

Comment: Совершенно согласна, что прежняя форма сдачи экзамена была чудовищной! Как я была счастлива, что мне не пришлось писать вступительное сочинение!  
Мне нравится ЕГЭ по математике, да и по русскому неплохое.  
И я совсем не против "репрессий" в определенных областях. На то и государство, чтобы устанавливать свои правила. Сама идея всеобщего образования - уже несвобода.    
Мой вопрос, по сути, чисто академический: почему знание языка (не просто умение грамотно писать) так важно в ментальности современного человека?  Я не говорю, что это плохо, не говорю, что хорошо. Мне интересно: почему?

Comment: "..Почему знание родного языка так важно в ментальности современного человека?"
 Язык определяет национальную принадлежность человека. Как же может быть по-другому?

Comment: Определяет именно потому, что человек "впитывает его с молоком матери", без всякого обучения. Веками русские люди говорили на русском языке, хотя даже в школу не ходили.

Comment: > Сама идея всеобщего образования - уже несвобода. 

Смотря с какой точки зрения посмотреть. Если рассматривать именно в ключе преподавания основ православной культуры - да, соглашусь. Тогда можно сделать вывод, что нашему государству нужно поколения послушных рабов. А с другой стороны - всеобщее обязательное бесплатное среднее образование - великое достижение советской власти, серьезно поднявшее уровень образования населения. Правда, не знаю как там было в глубинке, но в городах уж точно.

Comment: Форма власти тут ни причем. Это несвобода по самой своей сути. Потому что кто-то "наверху" решает, что именно должен делать каждый человек, чему учиться, что знать и уметь. Может, моему ребенку надо каждый день заниматься физкультурой, ИЗО и трудом? (у него проблемы с мелкой и крупной моторикой). А уж русскому и математике я его сама научу. А сколько людей забывают все, изученное в школе, едва выйдя из ее стен?  
Рекомендую почитать [вот это](http://gidepark.ru/community/702/content/701611): на меня произвело большое впечатление!

Comment: Почитал. Соглашусь, проблема имеет место быть. Вспоминается Pink Floyd c их "Another Brick In The Wall"

Comment: К сожалению, не знаю творчество этой группы. О чем там поется?

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, что наша дискуссия может оказаться бесконечной. Вот мы уже от заглавного вопроса перешли к разговору о ЕГЭ. По этой теме миллионы комментариев расположились на множестве сайтов,но зачастую люди спорили о ЕГЭ, не познакомившись детально с вопросами и заданиями, входящими в части А,В,С (об этом пишет и участница нашей полемики Лариса). Так случилось, что мне пришлось тесно столкнуться с заданиями ЕГЭ (позанимался с несколькими учениками), поэтому вправе судить об этом.Части А и В вполне нормальны. Главное, что они имеют практический характер. А вот часть С. - это ни в какие рамки не входит. Разработчики заданий предлагают выпускникам написать сочинение объемом 150-200 слов (примерно 1,5 - 2 страницы). Способны ли это сделать школьники? Нужно быть очень талантливым, образованным человеком, чтобы при таком ограниченном объеме текста сделать добротную письменную работу, которая содержала бы и формулировку проблемы с комментариями, и изложение позиции автора исходного текста, и изложение собственного мнения ученика по данному вопросу с примерами из жизни и литературы. Ладно бы только это. Но формалисты от системы образования пошли дальше. Они потребовали следовать жестким шаблонам в написании сочинения, и отступление от шаблонов строго пресекается с помощью сижения количества баллов по каждому критерию оценки сочинения.
     Вот тут уже я соглашусь с теми, кто отмечал репрессивный характер ЕГЭ. Требование написать сочинение так, как настаивают те чиновники, которые организуют это испытание, - это действительно насилие над личностью.
    Конечно, прежняя система выпускного сочинения в том виде, как она функционировала в последние годы до ЕГЭ, изжила себя, особенно после того, как на прилавках магазинов появились сотни сборников сочинений на любую тему (Каюсь, грешен, в 90-е и я по заказу одного издательства такой сборник написал). Система сочинений перестала работать и потому, что предлагались темы, одинаковые для всей страны (позже для региона). Хотя считалось, что темы объявляются только на самом экзамене, а в 80-е годы и 90-е для пущей важности это делалось по местному радио, однако за 3-4 дня до 1 июня школьники поголовно знали все названия тем. На самом экзамене большинство выпускников лишь добросовестно переписывали начисто то, что было заранее написано дома, причем отнюдь не всегда сочинение было написано дома самими учениками. Помню, как часто мне трудно было отказать близким знакомым в их просьбе написать сочинение для сына (дочери), претендующих на школьную медаль.  И все же форма выпускного сочинения была вполне неплоой. Механизм применения этой формы надо было усовершенствовать, и тогда не пришлось бы столько сил, нервов, огромных денег тратить на внедрение пресловутого ЕГЭ.
    К чему я все это пишу? Мы ведь не случайная группа, а группа единомышленников. Наше сообщество адептов сайта "Русский язык" могло бы составить какое-то письмо в Минобр с предложениями о совершенствовании системы ЕГЭ. Понимаю, что таких писем приходило в Министерство немало, но почему бы и нам не выполнить свой гражданский долг? Капля гору точит.

Comment: !50 - минимум. Объем не ограничен. Вполне хорошие сочинения получаются объемом около 300 слов.

Comment: Я, конечно, не специалист, но моя кузина - учитель литературы и Учитель года хвалит часть С. Мне тоже кажется, что написать небольшое изложение по готовому тексту все же легче, чем на 6 страницах обсуждать какой-нибудь "луч света в темном царстве". В конце концов, часть С - не для всех. Конечно, проверка сочинений - дело субъективное, тут уж ничего не поделаешь.

Comment: > Мы ведь не случайная группа, а группа единомышленников. Наше сообщество адептов сайта "Русский язык" могло бы составить какое-то письмо в Минобр с предложениями о совершенствовании системы ЕГЭ. Понимаю, что таких писем приходило в Министерство немало, но почему бы и нам не выполнить свой гражданский долг? Капля гору точит.  

Ну, полного единомыслия, по-моему, здесь нет. И, пожалуйста, не в моем вопросе...

Answer (score 1):

Грамотность сама по себе снобизмом вряд ли является. Разве что подчеркнутая грамотность вкупе с высокомерным поведением.

Answer (score 0):

Ой, какие страсти разгорелись! 
Я не считаю, что грамотность является формой снобизма. 
А правила и исключения школьникам надо знать. (Хотя бы для нормальной сдачи ГИА и ЕГЭ). И  грамотному человеку не надо чувствовать себя неловко перед безграмотными людьми.

Comment: Я не чувствуя себя неловко. Я чувствую свое превосходство, хотя, конечно, стараюсь его не показывать.   

Меня интересует __системный__ вопрос: почему общество выбрало именно эту сферу для жесткого регулирования? Ведь не вводят же ЕГЭ по ритмике, например! Или по приличному поведению! А было бы неплохо: и владение телом, и умение себя держать - ценные социальные качества.  

Веками язык развивался свободно, никто не заставлял людей (будь они даже дворянского происхождения) разбираться в падежах и наклонениях, думаю, даже не было точно известно, сколько "н" надо писать. И вот - на тебе! ЕГЭ!

Comment: Знаете, я когда-то работала в одном "сильно новаторском" учебном заведении . Однажды мы обсуждали вопрос, надо ли давать в гуманитарном классе математику, и сколько. Парадокс: гуманитарии были за расширение курса, а математики - против. Наверное, потому, что нам-то пришлось бы потом все это "вдалбливать" :((  

Я тогда поймала себя на мысли, что математика - это не для средних умов. Для небожителей (вроде меня). Шучу, конечно, но что-то такое подумалось.  Вот также и с русским: все равно грамотными будут единицы. Правда, не ясно заранее, кто именно.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, впервые слышу, что большинство говорит "звОнит". Многие и матом ругаются, так что, нам тоже надо?

Comment: Мат - неотъемлемая часть русской культуры. Надеюсь, это сомнению не подлежит. Так или иначе он присутствует в произведениях великих русских писателей. Другой вопрос, что культурный человек не будет ругаться как сапожник все время. Тем более в присутствии детей и женщин. Да и эмоциональная составляющая мата теряется при его постоянном употреблении. Потому что табуированная лексика используется в экстремальных ситуациях и позволяет либо быстро донести информацию до собеседника, либо разрядить эмоциональную обстановку.

Comment: Не в звОнит дело. Язык - живая система, и была такой многие века. "Нормирование" его началось, кода сложились нации и в этих нациях выросла лингвистическая наука. Школа уже несколько поколений внедряет норму в массовое сознание, но люди как говорили по-своему, так и говорят.  
Никто ведь не жалуется, что люди неправильно решают квадратные уравнения или делают химические опыты. Они этого просто _не делают_: это область для специалистов. А язык присутствует в нашей жизни с рождения. И у каждой группы населения он свой.  
Почему же я считаю, что правильным является только _мой_ язык?

Comment: Насчет звОнит. Не проводила социологических исследований, но в моем окружении (включая кафедру) говорящие так составляют не менее 75%. Я уж не говорю про обеспечЕние - здесь, наверное, все 90%.  И это нисколько не мешает им быть хорошими специалистами.  

Хотя, каюсь, у меня такое произношение вызывает внутренне "поскребывание". Тот самый снобизм в действии :((

Answer (score 0):

Вдогонку к вопросу о тотальной безграмотности (тому самому, который закрыт по причине "холивар"). Хотелось бы обратиться к господам Бегемотусу и Дерзкому: вместо того, чтобы выковыривать в произведениях классиков их мелкие "косяки" (а может, даже вовсе и не их, а издателей) и размахивать ими, как знаменем (наверное они при этом в гробу переворачиваются), посмотрите телепрограмму "Тотальная безграмотность" 5-го канала. Комментарии излишни. Респект создателям за то, что все эти вопросы были подняты на телевидении. Прежде чем обвинять кого-то в безграмотности и троллить, стоило бы представиться людям, кто вы есть по жизни и каковы ваши полные имена, дабы люди знали, кто же их обвиняет. Доктора филологических наук? Профессора (по старому профессорЫ) лингвистики? Однако вы почему-то постеснялись представиться и предпочитаете скрываться за никами. И если вы принимаете за аксиому любую ошибку, допущенную в литературном произведении или публицистике, то есть ли при этом у вас своя голова на плечах и способны ли вы вообще развиваться по жизни?
И по теме: если вам так хочется назвать людей, желающих возродить и очистить родной язык снобами, то пожалуй я сноб! Уж в этом вопросе точно сноб. Ибо уже противно...

Comment: Фройляйн Ангелика, как всегда, слишком категорична, но она все перепутала))) Я не ищу ошибков у классиков, я их просто читаю и привожу часто в пример именно их написание. Мне за это ставит жирные минусы компания бегемотуса)))))))  
Давайте дружить, Ангелика, мы с вами прекрасно споемся!  
Дерзкий grumant, можно Иоганн Вайс или Саша Белов, как вам понравится)))

Comment: Госпожа @Параллельная. А почему вы это пишите в моей теме? Заводите свою и там ругайтесь. Я поднимала здесь гораздо более тонкий и философский вопрос, который, к сожалению, не все смогли разглядеть. А стоны по поводу всеобщей безграмотности или наоборот, излишней требовательности к грамоте, пожалуйста, испускайте где-нибудь в другом месте.

Answer (score 0):

Если человек **считает**, что он грамотен, а другие нет, то это питательная среда снобизма - пренебрежительного отношения к "не своим".
Если человек **знает**, что он *возможно* грамотен, а другие *возможно* не грамотны, то и снобизма не будет.

В Интернете в статье "... эксперты назвали устаревшие правила русского языка." сказано:
"Одиозное слово «звонит», которое стало каким-то эталоном грамотности... Считается, что грамотные люди ставят ударение на «И» - звонИт, а остальные — на «О» - звОнит. ... Хочется специалистам по русскому языку, или нет — но будущее явно за вариантом «звОнит»!"

Чтобы понять кто прав, надо просто оценить логику языка. Например, мУсор - мУсорит. Молот - МолОтит, МолотОк - молотИт. Тогда возможно звОн - звОнит, а звонОк - звонИт. То есть, если ударение на корне существительного, то в глаголе ударение на корне; а если ударение на суффиксе существительного, то в глаголе ударение тоже на суффиксе. Колокол издает звон, значит он скорее звОнит. Телефон издает звонок, значит он звенИт или звонИт.
Таким образом, грамотный человек а) понимает, что грамотность (тогда когда она не влияет на понимание смысла) не более чем предмет общественного договора; б) понимает и принимает, что могут быть правильными оба варианта; в) может предложить разумные объяснения правильности обоих вариантов.

P.S. Обычно грамотный (по моему определению) человек снобизм не проявляет.