# Кого сегодня мы называем снобами?

Tags: лексика

Хотелось бы сформулировать понятие "сноб" в контексте реальной жизни. Есть подозрение, что значение этого слова меняется с течением времени. Возможно, сейчас мы его употребляем не совсем в том варианте, как написано в словарях и Википедии. Отвечая на многогранный вопрос @Docenti [Является ли грамотность формой снобизма](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0), я решила отдельно вынести этот вопрос на обсуждение. Подчеркну, что в первую очередь интересуют не академические версии, а жизненные: кто как понимает и может объяснить, кто такой сноб? Своими словами. Примеры из жизни только приветствуются. А позже можно будет сравнить с версиями из авторитетных источников.

Comment: Не считаю себя снобом, но когда слышу или вижу неправильное слово, выражение, мне нестерпимо хочется исправить говорящего или написавшего, что иногда и делаю автоматически...

Answer (score 7):

Я тоже не заглядывал в словарь, но могу определить сноба как человека высокомерного, кичащегося своей мнимой высококультурностью, значимостью, точнее значительностью своей личности и чванливым презрением к тем, кто, по его мнению стоит ниже его на социальной лестнице. При этом сноб ничего не делает, чтобы как-то изменить сложившуюся неблагоприятную социальную ситуацию. Сегодня таких снобов немало, в том числе среди тех, кто занимается пустым и трусливым критиканством, а сам палец о палец не ударит, чтобы принести пользу обществу, а значит, и своим близким.

Answer (score 5):

А я никого не называю. Следую определениям словаря.

*СНОБ, -а; м. [англ. snob]

1. В России до 1917 г.: 

о человеке, стремившемся строго следовать вкусам, манерам и т.п. высшего общества и с пренебрежением относившемся ко всему другому.

2. Неодобр.

Человек, считающий себя носителем высшей интеллектуальности и изысканных вкусов. < Снобистский, -ая, -ое. С-ие рассуждения. С-ие вкусы.*
БТС, Кузнецов

Единственное, что добавил бы, это убрал бы из первого определния 17-й год, ибо понятие вечно. А второе дополнил бы словами "с пренебрежением относящийся..." из первого. Сноб в себе - это не сноб. Он брюзжать должен на публике по поводу падения нравов и прочего.

Comment: А я скорее соглашусь, что первое определение характеризует снобов в России таки до 17-го года, так как после Октябрьской революции высшее общество вместе со всеми титулами попросту отменили. Люди же, стремившиеся в него попасть или подражать изысканным манерам, попросту исчезли. Не знаю, кого считали снобом в СССР (может, и никого), а вот сейчас этот "термин" расширился. Предполагаю, что снобом можно называть кого угодно в плане статуса, но главное, чтоб этот человек сам себя считал "крутым перцем" и отстранялся от тех, кого считает недостойным своего круга.

Comment: Да какая разница, пропали люди или нет? Разве само понятие "сноб" в первом значении претерпело изменение? Я понимаю ещё городовых - или там титулование по табели о рангах - отменили (хотя и тут сами понятия не претерпело изменение), но специально огововариваться, что "снобы" существовали до 17-го года - это смешно. Этак мы и про извозчиков будем говорить "до революции"

Comment: Если понятие существует только в теории, то оно устарело.

Answer (score 2):

В моем понимании сноб - человек прежде всего действительно успешный в чем-то. В остальном я согласна с Виктором, что это еще и высокомерный, чванливый, страдающий гордыней тип. Вот этот нюанс меня интересует: можно называть снобом того, кто на самом деле в чем-то профессионал, но на всех смотрит свысока? Или же это мнимый спец, который думает, что профессионал, а по правде говоря грош ему цена?

**Дополнение-ответ [[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus)** 
А разве 1-е и 2-е значения не отличаются друг от друга? 1-е: "О человеке, **стремившемся** строго следовать вкусам, манерам и т.п. высшего общества", то есть изначально неблагородного происхождения. "Популярная версия происхождения этого слова — сленговое название студентов Итонского университета в начале XIX века, где «нобы» (ученики благородного происхождения, вероятно от слова англ. noble — дворянин) противопоставлялись «снобам» (неблагородным). Но иногда утверждают, что слово происходит от сокращения «s. nob.» (от лат. sine nobilitate — неблагородного происхождения)." (Википедия) Снобы раньше (до 17-го года) обязательно противопоставлялись истинным аристократам. 
Разве сегодня мы не можем назвать снобом какого-нибудь потомственного аристократа или топ-менеджера крупной компании, если он считает себя лучше остальных и все это замечают, хоть даже он и не кичится этим? Раньше аристократов так не называли вовсе. По-моему, 1-е определение сноба можно считать устаревшим. Но это не значит, что снобы исчезли. Просто 2-е определение гораздо шире, и его можно считать современным. Мне очень сложно представить себе сноба эпохи СССР, ведь социальная иерархия отсутствовала просто-напросто (были богатые, но они никак не выставляли себя напоказ; и примерно все одинаково бедные). Сейчас же это понятие снова приобретает актуальность, так как есть богатые, есть средний класс, бедные и нищета. Еще олигархи. Или же более или менее успешные в чем-то люди. Если человек грамотный не желает общаться с менее грамотным, разве нельзя его назвать снобом? По-моему, это прозвучит не очень обидно, так как никто не отрицает факта грамотности этого человека. А если при этом подразумевать значение №1 (что человек на самом деле не такой грамотный, как он сам думает), это уже будет по-настоящему обидно. Не должны и не могут эти два значения (еще лучше их уточнить) быть актуальными сегодня, т. к. это порождает двусмысленность в общении. Понятие может быть вечным, но неактуальным на какой-то период, несовременным, каким и является сейчас, на мой взгляд, определение сноба №1. 
Понравилась [цитата](http://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1) на эту тему. Все-таки раньше снобизм был явно негативным явлением. Сегодня "сноб" звучит хоть и неодобрительно, но не всегда однозначно. Иногда даже с оттенком иронии или зависти. Или просто один хочет подчеркнуть какую-нибудь плохую черту характера другого, но не всегда понятно, какую именно.

Comment: Для меня в понятии "сноб" присутствует высокомерие (хотя бы и скрываемое), но нет смысла "мнимости". По-моему, сноб ставит себя выше других заслуженно, но пренебрежение к другим делает его "образ" отрицательным. Ну, и занудство в этом человеке тоже присутствует.

Comment: Да, очень даже соглашусь.

Answer (score 1):

Имхо, сноб это псевдоинтеллектуал, то есть человек хочет показаться более образованным, начитанным, культурным, чем он есть на самом деле. Он смотрит интеллектуальное кино, артхаус и т. д. не потому, что ему нравиться, а для того, чтобы прослыть человеком утонченным, но и интеллектуальное кино и артхаус ему не интересны, а может быть даже и скучны. Это человек, изучающий многие вещи поверхностно для того, чтобы в разговоре с неискушенным собеседником произвести на оного впечатление.

Answer (score 0):

Я не смотрел, что это слово значит в словарях, но сам употребляю его в значении занудства.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, когда-то это слово было синонимом аристократа и вообще, образованного человека, сейчас же в нем больше негативной коннотации, скорее синоним высокомерия (не исключено что обоснованного, но все же говорится с неудовольствием)